# Photon generation during electrostatic attraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, feynman-diagrams

Photons are the force carrier for the electromagnetic force. So, when two charged particles come in close vicinity of each other, they must experience the electromagnetic force which is carried by photons. But how photons are created in the first place and how is that energy compensated by the universe?

Answer (score -1):

Charge interaction has slightly more facets depending on which charges are interacting.

*Charge - Anti-Charge*
Obviously, both particles are converted into pure energy in the form of two or more photons.

*Two charges with the same charge*
The summary kinetic energy before and after the approach remains the same. No photons are emitted.

*Two charges with different charge*
This happens, for example, when an electron is attracted to an ion nucleus. This is known to be accompanied by the emission of photons.

> But how photons are created in the first place …

Electron and the proton in their atomic interaction have a weaker common field. The overdue field is emitted in the form of photons.

> … and how is that energy compensated by the universe?

There is no compensation at all. There is no balance at all between matter and energy. The number of photons and the number of subatomic particles are not constant values. The explosion of a plutonium bomb, in which energy is partially converted into energy, does not mean that somewhere else in the universe some energy is immediately converted into matter.